# TextFormField Validator not work in Flutter

Tags: flutter, text, textformfield

I've created a page where they can send the user a verification code.

But the validator doesn't work even if I create an if else case.
When I click the button (even if it's empty), it goes to the other page.
how can i fix this?

here is my full code;

I added it in the form widget after the last comments but it didnt work

```
   return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                      ),
                      FlatButton(
                        onPressed:(){
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          allTranslations.text('login'),
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            color: HexColor('#4A8EB0'),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Text(
                    allTranslations.text('signUp'),
                    style: textTheme.headline5,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    maxLines: 3,
                  ),
                ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: _controller,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              decoration: CommonInputStyle.textFieldStyle(
                hintTextStr: 'E-mail',
                labelTextStr: 'E-mail',
              ),
              validator: (value) =>
              value.isEmpty ? 'Password cannot be blank' : null,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 50.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                color: HexColor('#4A8EB0'),
              ),
              child: InkWell(
                onTap: () async {
                  setState(() {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context,AnotherPage.routeName);
                  });
                },
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Send Code',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: TextFormField must be a child of a Form widget and then on the Form widget you can call a method `validate`, but still, you have to do that manually.

Comment: Even though I enclose the form widget, it's still the same:/

Comment: do you call `validate` manually? Share the code please

Comment: I tried to print but I didn't get any results

Comment: please edit your post with your current code base. I'm guessing you are not correctly calling the validate method.

Comment: I updated my code @Limbou

Comment: in order to validate your form you have to call `_formKey.validate()` at some point in your code. For example on tapping a button.

Comment: I have no place to do such a thing _formKey.validate()

Answer (score 0):

As Limbou mentioned you need to validate when the user taps the button. It will return true if it succeeds.

```
onTap: () async {
   if(_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
       setState(() {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, AnotherPage.routeName);
       });
   }
}
```

Comment: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The method 'validate' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: validate()